# How to create azure DevOps pipeline for GitHub Enterprise repos as source using azure DevOps API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api, github-enterprise

I am trying to create pipeline with source repo as GitHub enterprise using following api and body -

POST [https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/pipelines?api-version=6.0-preview.1](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borg%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/pipelines?api-version=6.0-preview.1)

```
{
   "configuration": {
        "path": "azure-pipelines.yml",
        "repository": {
            "fullName": "GitUser/Repository",
            "connection": {
                "id": "xxxxxxx"
            },
            "type": "gitHubEnterprise"
        },
        "type": "yaml"
    },
    "name": "test-clone"
}
```

This throws error This API does not support creating pipelines with type GithubEnterprise

This works for GitHub

What changes do I need to do creating pipeline for gitHub Enterprise?

Comment: Please make sure your [GitHub Enterprise Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github-enterprise?view=azure-devops) is reachable from the servers that run Azure Pipelines service. Can you try to create a yaml pipeline manually? Then, use [Pipelines - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/pipelines/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)Rest API to check the configuration of this pipeline. Please also share the complete error message of the API.

Comment: Hi friend, would you please share your latest information about this issue?